# capistrano hang at git archive master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano3

ive been deploying my rails 5 project via capistrano, and it seems to hang at this line:

```
cd /home/username/rails-stg/repo && ( SASS_LIBSASS_PATH=/usr/local/libsass GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/username/tmp/projectname/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /home/username/rails-stg/releases/20160401154947 )
```

when i rm -R /home/username/rails-stg/repo & /home/username/rails-stg/releases, it works again!

what may be the cause of this issue?

I've to keep deleting this directory every time i cap staging deploy.
i tried deleting all entry in ~/.ssh/known_hosts, but problem still persists.

using capistrano (3.4.0), rails (5.0.3.beta)

Comment: How big is the repository?

Comment: hi, i tried du -hs repo, its 41mb, and when i tried to manually run that command, it did finish successfully within few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution. I was using Ruby 2.1.4 and I'm not sure which sshkit version I was using. After I deleted my Ruby 2.1.4 and install Ruby 2.2.4, and fresh with:

```
gem install capistrano capistrano-rvm capistrano-bundler i18n sshkit capistrano-rails capistrano-configuration net-scp net-ssh
```

it works!